# Comprobación de nombre de usuario existente no funciona (AJAX)

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Tengo un código en el que utilizo Ajax para comprobar la disponibilidad de un nombre de usuario ingresado, comparando con la base de datos en tiempo real, pero no funciona.

Ajax

```
<script>
    function disponibilidad(username) {
        $.ajax({
            url:'comprobarDisponibilidad.php',
            data:'username='+$("username").val(),
            type:"POST",
            success:function(data){
                $("#comprobarUsuario").html(data);
            },
            error:function (){}
        });
    }
</script>
```

PHP

```
<?php
    include 'database.php';

    if(!empty($_POST["username"])){
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=:username");
        $stmt->bindValue(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute(); 
        $count = $stmt->fetchColumn();

        if($count>0) {
            echo "<span style='color:red'> Sorry User already exists .</span>";
        }
        else{
            echo "<span style='color:green'> User available for Registration .</span>";
        }
    }
?>
```

La función "disponibilidad" la ejecuto acá, sumado al span que actualizo:

```
<input class="formulario__input" type="text" name="username" id="username" oninput="disponibilidad()" placeholder="Nombre de usuario">
<span id="comprobarUsuario"></span>
```

Saludos

Comment: Haz un `var_dump($_POST);` para que veas que datos te está llevando `ajax` a `PHP`. Al parecer estás concatenando esto `data:'username='+$("username").val(),` y deberías estar enviando solo el `value` del campo, algo como esto: `let username = $("#username").val(); $.ajax({... data : { 'username' : username },... });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estuve revisando tu código y tengo la solución.
Primero que nada no enviás el parámetro username a través de ajax te falto agregar `this.value`al hacer el llamado a la función con lo cual la función va sin parámetro.
debería quedar así:

```html
<input class="formulario__input" type="text" name="username" id="username" oninput="disponibilidad(this.value)" placeholder="Nombre de usuario">
```

El siguiente problema lo encontré en la función de ajax, no se sí tu función esta correcta, pero para poder enviar el parámetro, se debe usar de esta manera:

```
data:'username='+ username,
```

Quedando la función así :

```
<script>
    function disponibilidad(username) {
        $.ajax({
            url:'comprobarDisponibilidad.php',
            data:'username='+ username,
            type:"POST",
            success:function(data){
                $("#comprobarUsuario").html(data);
            },
            error:function (){}
        });
    }
</script>
```

Por ultimo en tu script php haces el llamado a una variable `$username` la cual nunca fue definida, así que primero la definimos y luego hacemos el llamado a la consulta, quedando de la siguiente forma:

```php
if(!empty($_POST["username"])){
    $username = $_POST["username"];
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE username=:username");
    $stmt->bindValue(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute(); 
    $count = $stmt->fetchColumn();

    if($count>0) {
        echo "<span style='color:red'> Sorry User already exists .</span>";
    }
    else{
        echo "<span style='color:green'> User available for Registration .</span>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Funciono perfectamente! Muchísimas gracias

Comment: Excelente , saludos.

Comment: Respuesta aceptada, saludos.